# Run a bash script on startup, before login as a user

Tags: bash, ubuntu-12.04, startup, ubuntu-server

I am trying to have my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server run a bash script I have to start a Minecraft server on start up, prior to log in but as user `minecraft`.  I can have it run as `root` by placing the following in `/etc/rc.local`

```
bash /path/to/script/script.sh
```

which runs the script as `root`, I have tried the following in `/etc/rc.local`

```
su -c `bash /path/to/script/script.sh` minecraft
```

but to no avail.  Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong or should be doing instead?  The first line of my script is

```
#!/bin/bash
```

in case it is important.  Thanks much!

Comment: `su - minecraft -c 'bash ...'`?

Comment: i had tried user first but when i look at the man page for su it seemed to me that user goes at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
su minecraft -c '/bin/bash /path/to/script/script.sh &'
```

- The user should be the first argument to su.
- You should use quotes and not ticks for the command argument (-c)
- You may want to consider using `su -l minecraft` to have the script run in an environment which would be similar to that if the user minecraft logged in directly.

Give this a shot and let me know if it works.

Comment: will let you know once i get off work and can give it a try,  thanks!